# How to stream music from pi to computer through browser interface?

Tags: pi-2, hard-drive, streaming

I have a Raspi with connected USB drive that contains my mp3 collection. It is currently set up as a NAS using Samba.

Is there a package that allows me to stream the music from the RasPi to my computer using a browser interface?

So similar to Spotify Open. The music is played by my PC and not by the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like subsonic, madsonic or airsonic (fork) are good solutions

Read more here:
http://www.subsonic.org/pages/installation.jsp#debian

Comment: The OP asked for packages. With `apt list subsonic madsonic airsonic` I cannot find any of the packages you suggested.

Comment: http://www.subsonic.org/pages/installation.jsp#debian

Comment: I would recommend Navidrome, a subsonic/airsonic compatible media server. There is no ready-made package, but have a look here: https://www.navidrome.org/docs/installation/linux/